# What is the differnece between "quickly" and "rapidly"?

Tags: adverbs, word-difference

What is the differnece between "quickly" and "rapidly"?

Here is an example:

> The technology is improving quickly while demand for the product increases rapidly.

Is it often intended to vary adverbs like this, or it is just a decoration?

Comment: [This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162644/fast-vs-quickly-vs-speedy-vs-rapidly) may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickly and rapidly are synonyms - they mean the same thing. They are probably used in such a way in the example so as to not sound repetitive. It would sound strange to say "The technology is improving quickly while demand for the product increases quickly."

In some cases I would say that "quickly" means faster than "rapidly" but that is a completely subjective opinion. They both mean fast, and the relative speed is not knowable or implied from the example sentence alone.

Comment: Is it correct to use "while" in the statement above? I think it's better to use "and" or "also".

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to say. "And" would be appropriate and might actually sound better. "Also" wouldn't sound as correct. You don't generally join clauses within a sentence using "also" - it is more for tying two different sentences together.